# What is a valid degree sequence for Networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I am trying to generate a power law degree distribution with a minimum degree value (rho) and use that to build a random graph with the networkx package. The function I am using to generate a power law degree distribution is like so (exponent is alpha and rho is the minimum value):

```
import random
import networkx as nx

def generate_pl_dd(no_of_nodes, alpha, rho):
  degree_distribution = []
  for i in range(no_of_nodes):
    r = random.random()

    degree_distribution.append(int(rho * (1 - r)**(-1/(alpha - 1))))

  return sorted(degree_distribution, reverse=True)
```

Now I wish to use the list of degrees generated by this function to build a networkx graph object. Before I do that, sanity checks like so return the following results.

```
dd1 = generate_pl_dd(100, 2.2, 50)
nx.is_valid_degree_sequence(dd1) # returns False
```

The documentation mentions that the sum of the degree sequence needs to be even, but even when I do generate an even summed degree sequence, the result is False. I have captured some runs of this function below.

```
dd2 = generate_pl_dd(100, 2.2, 50)
sum(dd2) # returns 15710
nx.is_valid_degree_sequence(dd2) # returns False

dd3 = generate_pl_dd(100, 2.2, 10)
sum(dd3) # returns 4540
nx.is_valid_degree_sequence(dd3) # returns False

dd4 = generat_pl_dd(100, 2.2, 1)
sum(dd4) # returns 344
nx.is_valid_degree_sequence(dd4) # returns True
```

How does the last run return True? What is the detail I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid degree sequence as tested by `is_valid_degree_sequence` is a sequence that a **simple** graph (a simple graph has no self-loops and no repeated edges) could have.  So for example you cannot have a graph with only two nodes, both having degree 3.  This example is pretty obviously impossile, but in general, the specific condition for a sequence to be "graphical" is a more involved calculation, usually done through the [Havel-Hakimi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm).

When you say "The documentation mentions that the sum of the degree sequence needs to be even", I believe you're referring to the [documentation](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.configuration_model.html?highlight=configuration_model) for `configuration_model`, which actually generates multigraphs (allowing self-loops and multiple edges).  The only restriction for it to do this is that the sum of the input degrees should be even (and as a technical detail, the self-loops are counted twice towards the degree in the generation process, though in other contexts they may count just once).

(for what it's worth --- `configuration_model` used to test that the degree sequence was "graphical", but [not anymore](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/133).  I claim some responsibility for this.)